# Notation for Conditional probability distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables defined on that space, mapping to $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{C})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{D})$, respectively.

The distribution of $X$ is the pushforward measure $\mathbb{P}_X(C):=\mathbb{P}(X\in C):=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=C\})$, for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$.

My question is now how the conditional distribution can be written in terms of a set $\{\omega\in\Omega: ?\}$, i.e.,
$\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y=y}(C)=\mathbb{P}(X\in C \mid Y=y)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:?\})$

Comment: You can't. Because the measure function $\Bbb P$ is altered under the new $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y)$.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate on this a little bit? To me it seems weird that we cant write it in that way since after all for any fixed $y$ its just a probability distribution on X so we should be able to write it just like the marginals in that manner...

Comment: It involes division i.e. $P(X\in C|Y=y) = P(X\in C, Y=y) / P(Y=y)$ (assuming the denominator >0 of course)

Answer (score 0):

So if someone comes across this question: It really just means

$\mathbb{P}(X\in C|Y)=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(C)|Y)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=C\}|Y)$

See Definition 26 in
[https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~arinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Notes/lec_notes_6.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36752/S18/Notes/lec_notes_6.pdf)

where conditioning on $Y$ means conditioning on the sigma algebra generated by $Y$.